# Moving entire vector within an array

Tags: c++, vector

I have an array of vectors, and I would like to delete an entry (in this case at index `3` of the array), and move all vectors up 1 position to fill the deleted slot.

I currently have two methods that works.

**Option 1** Swap each vector: `std::swap(m_conditions[i], m_conditions[i+1]);`

**Option 2** Copy each vector: `m_conditions[i] = m_conditions[i + 1];`

I feel that I should be able to `move` these vectors around without copying and swapping, can anyone suggest a better approach? (Without replacing the `m_conditions` array with a vector)

```
#include <vector>

class clsCondition
{
public:
    int conditionValues;
};

int main()
{

    int arrayCount = 50;
    int deleteEntry = 3;
    std::vector<clsCondition> m_conditions[50];

    for (int i = deleteEntry; i < arrayCount - 1; i++)
    {
        //std::swap(m_conditions[i], m_conditions[i+1]); // Option 1 Swap each vector
        m_conditions[i] = m_conditions[i + 1];  // Option 2 Copy each vector
    }
    arrayCount--;
    m_conditions[arrayCount].clear();

}
```

Comment: This declaration of an array  std::vector<clsCondition> m_conditions[50]; does not make sense. It seems you need to declare a vector with 50 elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make option 2 move the vector rather than copying it, change your code as below

```
m_conditions[i] = std::move(m_conditions[i + 1]);
```

Your option 1 with the swap *will* move rather than copy; however, doing the move yourself is probably clearer.